# becameValid does not get triggered

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to know when a record in ember-data has been successfully saved in the same way I can successfully know that it has become invalid like this:

```
exercise.one 'becameInvalid', (result) ->
  WZ.Utils.generateErrorSummary.call(exercise)
```

I would have thought that becameValid would behave in the same way:

```
exercise.one 'becameValid', (result) ->
  WZ.Utils.notify 'Exercise created!'
```

Obviously it does not, it does not get triggered i the same way.

Should it be?

Comment: According to [Ember's guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/model-lifecycle/), there is no such event `becameValid`.

Comment: If you're creating a new record, you should use `didCreate` event, and if you are updating, use `didUpdate`..

Comment: becameValid is in the source

Comment: Yes, but is has another purpose. It is a message(or event) that *you* can send(or trigger) using `record.send('becameValid');` on a model to tell ember that it is valid after the `becameInvalid` or `becameError` event happened.